# @Html.DropDownList fails on Selected = true

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It seems that the @Html.DropDownList fails to render  with Selected value set. I have an example:

```
@foreach (SelectListItem item in ViewBag.Agare as List<SelectListItem>)
{
    <div>
        Item: Name: @(item.Text) Value: @(item.Value) Selected: @(item.Selected)
    </div>
}
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Agare", ViewBag.Agare as List<SelectListItem>, new {@class = "chzn-select" })
</div>
```

And the result is :

Name: Demo Yacht Club Value: 1 Selected: False

Name: Anders Jansson Value: 100 Selected: False

Name: Per Kyrk Value: 101 Selected: False

Name: Oskar Persson Value: 102 Selected: True

Name: Pluten Snutten Value: 204 Selected: False

**And the first options is always default value!**

Rendered code is:

```
  <select class="chzn-select" id="Agare" name="Agare" required="required">
    <option value="1">Demo Yacht Club</option>
    <option value="100">Anders Jansson</option>
    <option value="101">Per Kyrk</option>
    <option value="102">Oskar Persson</option>
    <option value="204">Pluten Snutten</option>
 </select>
```

Its worth mentioning that I also use Choosen to style the DropDown, but it does not matter if I stop using it. Otherwise it is very straight forward everything!

And my versions are:
Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.
MVC 5.0.0
Asp.Net Razor 3.0.0
Asp.Net Web API 5.0.0
Asp:net Web Pages 3.0.0
EF 6.0.1
chosen 0.12.0

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Please try changing the name of your DropDownList 'Agare' to be different from your ViewBag property. Strange, I know!

```
@Html.DropDownList("SomethingElse", ViewBag.Agare as List<SelectListItem>, new {@class = "chzn-select" })
```

Comment: Nothing strange at all. In simple words, the helper uses collection supplied `Selected` property if it doesn't find ViewData supplied value with given key, in this case "Agare". Otherwise it rebuilds the selectlist and sets option to selected if `option.value == ViewData["Agare"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ViewBag`. Having a better solution is more important than just making the problem work. If you search the internet for "ViewBag SelectListItem not working", you can find a lot, that is why I am suggesting you to use VIewModel.

below is an example.

**ViewModel**

```
public class SportsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedSports { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sportses { get; set; } 
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Sport()
{
    var model = new SportsViewModel();
    //_sportses is a list for sports
    // get selectedSprortsId value for dropdown selected item. 
    model.Sportses = _sportses.Select(m => new SelectListItem {Value = m.Id.ToString(), Text = m.Name, Selected = m.Id == selectedSprortsId});

       return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model SportsViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Sportses)
{
    <div>
        Item: Name: @(item.Text) Value: @(item.Value) Selected: @(item.Selected)
    </div>
}
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedSports", Model.Sportses, new { @class = "chzn-select" })
</div>
```

**Update:**

If you cann't change to `ViewModel`, you can use `SelectList`,and set all list to your ViewBag like below:

```
   var SelectListItemList = (from s in _sportses
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = s.Name,
                          Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                      }).ToList();

    ViewBag.Agare = new SelectList(SelectListItemList , "Value", "Text", selectedSprortsId);
```

Then in your view, you still can your existing code just delete "`as List<SelectListItem>`".

```
@foreach (SelectListItem item in ViewBag.Agares)
{
    <div>
        Item: Name: @(item.Text) Value: @(item.Value) Selected: @(item.Selected)
    </div>
}
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.DropDownList("Agare", ViewBag.Agare as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "chzn-select" })
```

Comment: Having a better solution is nice, but definitely not more important than having something that works.

Comment: Hi @Ant P,  you would just try to make something work, and not consider having a better solution or having the solution be maintainable... A better solution implies that it works, which is why it's called a solution, only better.

Comment: Can't do!! Other code are dependent on the name Agare, such as LaberFor, Validation and form field data used when form is submitted. The model is constructed Database First EF, and maintained that way, so editing and changing is not a option. Works on multiple other places, just not here!!! Why!!

Comment: Well, your updated code is the same code I use!!!! I do build a List<SelectListItem> and put it in the ViewBag so, the question is still, why does it not work!

Comment: @Lin No, I wouldn't "just try to make something work and not consider having a better solution," (and never said anything of the sort) but you implied that elegance is *more important* than functionality, which is going to leave you with a lot of very pretty useless code. Maybe your phrasing was off.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder what part of better solution implied elegant but useless code. Better solution means having better functionality. Some argument there.

Answer (score 0):

Changed name of ViewBag property, and now it works.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Agare", ViewBag.ListOfAgare as List<SelectListItem>, new { required = "required", @class = "chzn-select" })
```

Why is that?

Comment: Does the reply from @Zabavsky to my answer provide what you need?

Comment: No, don't think so. The last sentence is confusing to me! Never use ViewData, only models and ViewBag properties!